# How to convert an array (with TRUE and FALSE values) to binary string to ASCII characters?

Tags: php, arrays, string, binary, ascii

I have a list of permissions arranged in an array, for example:

```
$permissions = array(true, true, false, false, true, ...);
```

My intention is to convert the array to a chain of 1's and 0's:

```
$pseudo_binary = array_to_binary($permissions); //011001000110111101100111
```

And then consider that string as a binary number and stored in the database as an ASCII word:

```
$ascii = binary_to_word($pseudo_binary); //dog
```

The *array-to-binary()* method is not important, I use a simple foreach. But I ask for help to do these conversions:

> (string)'011001000110111101100111' -----> 'dog'
>
> 'dog' -------> (string)'011001000110111101100111'

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: What I've found is how to handle a _binary number_, not a _string representing a binary number_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

First I go through each element with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and replace `TRUE` -> `1`, `FALSE` -> `0`. Then I [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) it into a string.

After this I simply [`str_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) your string into an array of 8 bits (1 byte). Then I loop through each array element with `array_map()`, convert the binary to dec with [`bindec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bindec.php), and then get the [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) character of it with [`chr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php). (Also note, that I used [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) to make sure each element has 8 bits, otherwise I would fill it up with 0's).

Code:

```
<?php

    //Equivalent to: 011001000110111101100111
    $permissions = [FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE];

    $binaryPermissionsString = implode("", array_map(function($v){
        return $v == TRUE ? 1 : 0;
    }, $permissions));


    $binaryCharacterArray = str_split($binaryPermissionsString, 8);
    $text = implode("", array_map(function($v){
        return chr(bindec(sprintf("%08d", $v)));
    }, $binaryCharacterArray));

    echo $text;

?>
```

output:

```
dog
```

Comment: question, why do I have to split the string into an array of 8 characters?  Can I not run the string as a whole?

Comment: @Srini `chr()` is only for 1 character, so 1 byte for each ASCII character.

Comment: Ah, _bindec()_. First I'm a little embarrassed to know that there was a function for that. But sometimes it is quite difficult to find proper documentation.Thank you very much for your answer, it is perfect.